# How to convert a JSON file to a PHP file, with the PHP file containg a return []; for include()'ing?

Tags: php, json

The JSON file is about 15.000 lines, with a max nesting level of 7. A `json_decode()` takes between the 1.4 and 2.1 seconds, after about 15 checks. I've manually transformed the JSON file to a PHP file, with an additional array surrounding it, with a `return` in front of it. Reading and processing takes 0.03 seconds now.

Example JSON file:

```
{
  "lvel1": {
      "level2": {
          "level3": [
              1,
              85151,
              895151,
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

Desired PHP file:

```
return [
  "lvel1" => [
      "level2" => [
          "level3" => [
              1,
              85151,
              895151,
          ]
      ]
   ]
];
```

Is there easier way of doing this? Results have yielded nothing, as it always comes down to "converting JSON to Array PHP".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = '...';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$phpOutput = 'return ' . var_export($arr, true);
```

Comment: Ah, beautiful! Had heard of `var_export` a long time ago, but never occured to me it might be that easy. One small caveat: I wish it would return short array notations, but this is great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to generate PHP like code to write to a file to prevent manually having to convert the JSON to php.

For example

```
<?php

$array = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
];


// This bit just creates an example json file to read
// a bit like you have in your example, but smaller
$json = json_encode($array);
file_put_contents('data.json', $json);

// Let's read it again just to show how to retrieve it
$retrieved = file_get_contents('data.json');

// Make it into a PHP array
$newArray = json_decode($retrieved);

var_export($newArray, true);

// Save it into a php file with a return and a ;
file_put_contents('data.php', "return {$phpArray};");
```

data.php then contains

```
return array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'd',
);
```

Comment: You're on the ball, but a tad too late :-).

Comment: It was @Evert's `$json = '...'` which beat me to the punch